# Ruby command line MVC framework?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, shell, command-line

I'm looking to write an app for the shell, *nix mostly. And I'm currently in love with Ruby, especially the 'rails way'.

So if there was a framework that applied rails like concepts to the commandline in ruby then that would be really fantastic.

I'v allready looked into SimpleCommand and Hirb, nothing quite what I was looking for.

To elaborate:

What I'm really looking for is a way to use a rails like (directory and application) structure to create a MVC command line application. So basically something like rails that doesn't respond to http, but instead reads and writes to the console.

Its *not* a shell, if i wanted that then irb works fine. It would be more like your options are A,B,C and they would work a bit like http links.

Comment: Please elaborate. What do you want to accomplish? For instance you can use ActiveRecord, ActiveResource, ... in scripts. If you pose a less abstract question, we could help you with better suggestions and/or examples.

Comment: Do you mean something like turbovision for ruby?  See http://tvision.sourceforge.net/ -- Or do you mean just a really complicated command line application, like ghostscript or something...which doesn't really have much in the way of gui...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should take a look at `boson` and `hirb` [2d] menus. First one for creation of commands, second one - for A,B,C options and custom/dynamic views for outputting data.

Comment: Its not really the view end of things im most concerned about. Its the Model and Controller, and something like routing.

Comment: Thanks, hirb is going to be very helpful.

Comment: "Thanks, hirb is going to be very helpful" <- Had you not mentioned hirb in your question before this comment?

Answer (score -1):

Maybe you should try `script/console` in your rails app. Is that what you wanted?

Comment: No, I'm looking to create a MVC app. Ruby != Rails.

Comment: How would you go about creating a MVC app in irb??

Comment: I know Ruby != Rails. But its your job to make your question clear.